# Best Meteor Host and Full Details

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment, hosting

Could any one tell me the detail for Meteor Deployment A-Z. I know about `mupx` and I've deployed client's Meteor apps to server. But i wanna know about A-Z detail for which server hosting is best for it and how to use it? And what about mongodb? We use local in development. What when we deploy it? What is the limit of it?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor best hosting platform is **HEROKU**.  And Best build package is [Meteor Buildpack](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse)

And database usage you can integrate **mLab** in heroku dashboard. Many packages are available depending on your data usage.